# Validate certain string using RegEx

Tags: regex, nsregularexpression

I need to validate following string using Regular Expressions.
These are the constraints which apply for this string.

1. From beggining it has 9 numbers.
2. In the end it has character 'V' or 'X'. They can be simple or capital.
3. Whole length of string must be 10.

Ex: 84256142V, 547812375X

Can anyone provide me RegEx for validate this.

Comment: If you willing to spend a bit, RegExBuddy is great for allowing mere mortals to write regex's

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`^\d{9}[VX]$` if you put the regex engine in case-insensitive mode, `^\d{9}[vVxX]$` otherwise.

Comment: @Sachira Be aware that that Regex will match non-euroamerican digits, like `০` BENGALI DIGIT ZERO (the ০ is your digit :-) ). In fact, it will match any character from [Number, Decimal Digit](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Nd/list.htm) (found here [NSRegularExpression_Class](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html), read under `\d`).

Comment: @Cat++ ah..is there any way to avoid such confusion?in my problem, given format is National Identity Card number which only use in my contry. So, to my application, there will not be much confusion, but to my future knowledge, it'll help me a lot. :) thanx again.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on the language, but it will be something like this:

```
^[0-9]{9}[VvXx]$
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the Regex you need: `/^(\d){9}(V|X)$/i`